# Android set CardView to half RecyclerView height

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

**Setup:**

I have an Activity which has a BottomNavBar + fragment containing my RecyclerView.
The RecyclerView should take all the space above the BottomNavBar.
The RecyclerView always dispays 2 CardViews, which should each take 50% of the RecyclerView's space (so basically rVHeight = ScreenHeight-BottomNavBarHeight). Seems easy enough, yet I can't figure out how to do it.

**Problems:**

1. The RecyclerView takes whole screen, not respecting NavBarHeight.
2. The computed values don't seem to match actual screen size...

**activity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
>

    <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
            android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">



        <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                tools:context=".ui.MainActivity">

            <fragment
                    android:id="@+id/navHostFragment"
                    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    app:defaultNavHost="true"
                    app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_main"
                    android:clipToPadding="false"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/bottomNavView"

            />

            <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
                    android:id="@+id/bottomNavView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@android:color/white"
                    app:menu="@menu/menu_bottom_nav"
                    app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            />

        </RelativeLayout>


        <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
                android:id="@+id/drawerNavView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                app:itemIconTint="#8b8b8b"
                app:itemTextColor="#666666"
                app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu" />

    </androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>

</layout>
```

**fragment.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerViewClash"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false">

    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**card_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"

        card_view:cardElevation="8dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <!--*************visible part****************************-->
        <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/ivRoot"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                card_view:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                card_view:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/relLayoutHashtags"
                card_view:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                card_view:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        >

            <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/clash_image"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:src="@drawable/image_placeholder"/>
            <View
                    android:id="@+id/vBgWin"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/bg_win_circle_background"
                    android:visibility="gone"/>

            <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ivWin"
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:scaleType="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_win_white"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:visibility="invisible"/>


            <!--*****************invisible part to expand on click****************************-->


            <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/rlCollapsingPart"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:visibility="invisible">
<!--                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"-->


                <FrameLayout
                        android:id="@+id/bgCollapsingPart"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                             android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:background="@color/white"
                            android:alpha="0.5">
                </FrameLayout>



                <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/relLayoutWithDescription"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <RelativeLayout
                            android:id="@+id/relLayoutThumbnail"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

                        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                                android:id="@+id/avatarThumbnail"
                                style="@style/icon"
                                android:src="@drawable/defaultavatar"/>

                        <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/username_text"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                tools:text="willsmith"
                                android:textColor="@color/black"
                                android:textStyle="bold"
                                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/avatarThumbnail"
                                android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>



                        <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/comment_image"
                                android:layout_height="45dp"
                                android:layout_width="45dp"
                                android:padding="10dp"
                                android:src="@drawable/ic_comment"
                                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/bookmark_image"/>

                        <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/bookmark_image"
                                android:layout_height="45dp"
                                android:layout_width="45dp"
                                android:padding="10dp"
                                android:src="@drawable/ic_bookmark"
                                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/more_image"/>

                        <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/more_image"
                                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                                android:layout_height="45dp"
                                android:layout_width="45dp"
                                android:padding="10dp"
                                android:src="@drawable/ic_more_vert_black"/>

                    </RelativeLayout>



                    <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/caption_text"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:paddingStart="10dp"
                            android:textColor="@color/black"
                            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/relLayoutThumbnail"
                            tools:text="willsmith This is a caption for the post. It's actually a very long caption."/>

                </RelativeLayout>




            </RelativeLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>





        <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relLayoutHashtags"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="24dp"
                card_view:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ivRoot"
                card_view:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                card_view:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/expand">


            <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                      android:paddingRight="5dp"
                      android:text="#Hashtag1"
                      android:id="@+id/tv1"/>

            <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                      android:paddingRight="5dp"
                      android:text="#Hashtag2sdf"
                      android:id="@+id/tv2"
                      android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tv1"/>

            <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                      android:paddingRight="5dp"
                      android:text="#Hashtagdsfgdfg1"
                      android:id="@+id/tv3"
                      android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tv2"/>


        </RelativeLayout>

        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/expand"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_expand"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                card_view:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                card_view:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ivRoot"/>


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

**Adapter.kt**

Like I explained, I try to compute the space allowed for the RecyclerView, which should be `TotalScreenHeight - BottomNavBarHeight`. Then I should have `rVHeight/2 - 24*2-16` (24*2 for the small bar with the TextViews and 16 for 2*8dp margin). I also resize the image itself or it would be bigger because of `WRAP_CONTENT` and the way Glide works.

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {

    val photo = photos[position]
    val width = holder.view.resources.displayMetrics.widthPixels
    val height = holder.view.resources.displayMetrics.heightPixels
    val rVHeight = height-navHeight

    holder.view.ivRoot.layoutParams.height = rVHeight/2-(24*2+16) //resize container for hidden views
    with(holder.view) {
        GlideApp.with(holder.view.context).load(photo.imageURL)
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
            .override(width,rVHeight/2-(24*2+16)) //resize to load proper height
            .into(clash_image)
             ...
    }
```

Quick image of how it looks like. As you can see, the bottom CardView is cut.

[image]

Comment: I think you could look for a code that gets the device's screen sizes, especially the height, then set an adapter's height to half of the device's height.

Comment: I already did that. Somehow the adapter is still the wrong size. Plus that doesn't work since the adapter has to take the whole screen except the BottomNavBar, and then be split into 2 CardViews!

Comment: I think `holder.view` will return the adapter's root view and not the `RecyclerView`'s view. You need the `RecyclerView`'s dimension for it. Also, it is better to show a small part of the lowest visible adapter so that the user knows that there are more underneath the list.

Comment: I found the main problem: I had calculation problems because I didn't convert dp to px properly.

Comment: Good for you. .